# Is there more elegant way to cast list of integers to array of WORD (of C_Types) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting

I have a list of integers - data variable (holds 115 integers
I need to write those integers to C_Type structure defined ( WORD * 115)

First I tried casting :

```
sentData.Data = (WORD * 115)(data) # Not working
```

The only way I can make it work is:

```
cnt=0
for i in data:
     sentData.Data[cnt] = i
     cnt +=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to unpack your data:

```
sentData.Data = (WORD * 115)(*data)
```

Also note that there is a more pythonic way for your solution:

```
for cnt, i in enumerate(data):
    sentData.Data[cnt] = i
```